# Get PayPal account type using GetAdvancedPersonalData API

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Hi I need to get **PayPal** account type (personal, pro, merchant, etc) using some sort of API call. I am looking into `GetAdvancedPersonalData` API, however in the documentation I don't see account type as a info I can retrieve.

First of all, is this possible?

If not what are my options?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to be either pro or merchant holder to be able to use APIs.

If you are a personal account holder you can not authorise another provider to access your account through API

In your paypal account (sandbox or live) go to Profile > My Selling Preferences, If you do not see an API link there, means you need to upgrade your account to either a pro or merchant

Comment: That is not my question, my question is asking for an existence of such a API call. (Get user's PayPal account type)